# How to store Spring Boot RequestBody as JSONObject to a particular collection in MongoDB

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Technology used: Spring-Boot, MongoDB

**Problem Statement**:

Instead of having POJO with `@Document`, and then writing RestController API and Repository using models, I want to have RequestBody with `JSONObject`.  I want to persist this JSON into particular collection in `mongodb`.

Normally, we would specify `@Document(collection="collName")` on the POJO Class, but I want to test on `JSONObject` itself,

how do I achieve to write it to particular collection in `mongodb` without specifying the collection it creates new collection with `JSONObject` name and stores in it.

**i.e**. If in Restcontroller API, I write this,

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(string);
```

then, it will create collection with name jsonObj

Comment: Hey, Welcome to SO. The community here will be able to help more if you can describe the problem you are facing more clearly and the solution that you have tried, preferably with code snippets. This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Not sure I fully got the question, but check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42414558/5873923) for a possible hint about working with the json string in a rest controller.